# Why is my mob farm nor producing any mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play 1.14.4 java edition with my friends in an Aternos server. I built a mob farm at y=105 with an afk spot at y=158. Its a standard single platform farm with a 30 meter drop. the platform is comletely dark. [image]

The caves underneath the farm is completely lighted.
[image]
[image]
Even when I am the only one online in the server the farm doesn't work and moreover the number of hostile mobs in the over-world seems almost zero.

Comment: Isn't Aternos an operating system? I don't think that's relevant for this. But more information in other regards would be helpful, like if mobs spawn elsewhere, what F3 shows as the loaded entity count, etc.

Comment: I read "water flows" on you subtitles. Is your whole farm flouded? That would stop the spawning

Comment: nope its not flodded the dispensers just triggered at that moment

Comment: The E in F3 shows 55/90 towards farm from afk spot

Comment: In first dark image(hard to see) i think i can see that you may be using stone half slabs?, these need to be placed at the correct block level, if they cover half the blocks level, you wont get spawns.

Comment: they are upper half slabs